SOQL query returns null field values for lookup fields when used by non admin users
I have a custom object with several custom lookup fields to other custom objects. I have a Apex class (not a trigger) that uses SOQL. And, when I traverse the lookup field and retrieve a field attribute from a related record, the value returned is null or empty string. However, this is not the case for an admin user because a value is returned.
The Apex class has with sharing applied to it and the SOQL query runs in system context. I think the issue might be field/object level security, but shouldn't the system context of the query circumvent this? Could this be a sharing issue and should I try running the code without sharing? Any tips/pointers will be appreciated.
Note: I pass the values from Apex onto a LWC component where the null attributes are being seen.

Almost certainly due to sharing, not permissions, given it's Apex with sharing. Whether you should make it without sharing depends on what you need to do with this data, and whether you may "leak" information out to the user that they should not actually see.

Looks to be a permission issue than a sharing issue. Check the permission of the user

Phil has the correct answer. Not sure how to mark the question as answered
